# GRUB loads recovery and NOT Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, laptop, hp-pavilion

I've been wondering why my computer is loading GRUB recovery and not Ubuntu, I believe this could be because the laptop battery died while the package manager was running and the package manager was setting up the kernel. Plus, can I copy the kernel from the live cd to the hard drive, and how can I do it?

Comment: You may be able to complete the kernel install (or install another kernel from recovery mode. Do you have any older kernels to use instead?

Comment: @Wilf I have a Live CD, and another PC that has a kernel I can copy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the situation. Is it a new install? How big is the drive?

GRUB has issues with larger drives, it cannot find the boot file as it cannot search very far. Best way around this is to make a small partition at the beginning of the drive with the boot on it. (needs to be a /boot drive)

Comment: I re-installed Ubuntu, good thing I had a backup partition.